# Show different content in sidebar based on user behaviour

Tags: php, cookies

I'm planning a site and I was thinking would it be possible to show alternate content in the sidebar based on the behaviour of the visitor? Say the user has clicked on link X on page A and I want the alternate content in the sidebar to be shown on page B, if they clicked on the link. Also, if the visitor fills out a form, would it be possible to associate the tracking cookie information with the submitted form to see what pages the visitor viewed? Would this be easier to implement in a particular cms?

I would appreciate it if someone could at least point me into the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can do all of this with PHP sessions. This is abstract answer to abstract question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes anything is possible & no need for cookies (unless you want to keep a persistent track of the user)

Have a relationship column next to the content in your db, when creating the content assign this value much like a category or tag ect.

Then when user clicks on link A as the page loads store its relationship in the session, then when link B is clicked load content related to the previous set session value.

Comment: You can also make predefined sidebar info inside db table that loads content based on HTTP_REFERER data.